# Mark dispute as settled (local currency api)

Tags: facebook

Our app has implemented local currency payments. We are now in the process of implementing disputes resolution. According to the docs app developers are supposed to e-mail the user to reach an agreement and then we must either do a refund or mark the dispute as settled.

You can refund a dispute by calling the graph API endpoint "/PAYMENT_ID/refunds" but I have found no documentation on how to mark the dispute as settled (when no refund is necessary). Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to communicate with a facebook developer and they told me that "marking a dispute as settled" is a feature that's still in development. We don't have to worry about it for now. Just refund the disputes that need to be refunded and ignore the rest.

Comment: Yes for the moment the only way to settle a dispute is to refund. You can't settle a dispute when you're not refunding. Local currency payments are not feature complete even though it's mandatory to use them now :(